# how to apply custom-values.yaml on two subchart which is part for main chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Chart.yaml:-

```
dependencies:
     - name: prometheus-operator
       version: 8.16.1
       repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
     - name: fluentd-elasticsearch
       version: 9.4.2
       repository: https://kiwigrid.github.io
```

Custom-values.yaml

```
# Change default node-exporter port
prometheus-node-exporter:
  service:
    port: 30206
    targetPort: 30206
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    storageSpec:
       volumeClaimTemplate:
         spec:
           storageClassName: efs
           accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
           resources:
             requests:
               storage: 5Gi
         selector: {}
elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["https://vpc-logs-abcd:443"]
```

Running command:-

```
helm install --namespace dependency test -f /root/custom-values.yaml  /root/customchart
```

Error/Problem:- Custom-values.yaml is NOT applied on the chart !! Chart Installed with "Default values"

Comment: You probably need to move those settings under `prometheus-operator:` and `fluentd-elasticsearch:` blocks in the `custom-values.yaml` file; otherwise they won't get passed on to the dependency charts.

Comment: can you help me where exactly i need to put ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/) to pass value in subchart you need to define value under dependent chart name section like following

```
prometheus-operator:
# Change default node-exporter port
  prometheus-node-exporter:
    service:
      port: 30206
      targetPort: 30206
  prometheus:
    prometheusSpec:
      storageSpec:
         volumeClaimTemplate:
           spec:
             storageClassName: efs
             accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
             resources:
               requests:
                 storage: 5Gi
           selector: {}

fluentd-elasticsearch:
  elasticsearch:
    hosts: ["https://vpc-logs-abcd:443"]
```

Answer (score 1):

When Helm installs a dependency chart, [only the values under the dependency's name are made visible to that chart](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#scope-dependencies-and-values).  When for instance the [prometheus-operator chart documentation](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator#configuration) lists configuration values, those need to be underneath the name of the dependency in your `custom-values.yaml`.

So your values need to be rearranged to look like:

```yaml
prometheus-operator: # dependency name from requirements.yaml/chart.yaml
  prometheus:
    prometheusSpec:
      storageSpec: { ... } # as you have it
  prometheus-node-exporter:
    # (Some settings are under nodeExporter; "service" isn't listed
    # in the chart docs)
    ...

fluentd-elasticsearch: # settings for the other dependency
  elasticsearch:
    hosts: ["https://vpc-logs-abcd:443"]
```